# How to get error message in postman instead of console

Tags: node.js, postman, mern

I am using node.js. I am getting the errors in the console window but I want it in the postman result.
Following is the code:

```
  try {
    const { username, email, password } = req.body;

    if (!username || !email || !password) {
      throw {
        status: 400,
        message: "All parameters are required"
      };
    }
    const result = await authController.newUser(username, email, password);
    console.log(result);
    res.status(200).json({
      status: 200,
      data: result.result.data,
      message: "User created successfully"
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    next(error);
  }
});
```

[image: console]

I want this message to be shown in the postman rather than in the console.

Answer (score 0):

For expression version < 5, you must call `next(err)` instead of `throw err` to invoke express's [default error handler](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html). You can also not use the default handler and return yourslef with

```
res.status(400).json({
    message: "All parameters are required",
});
return;
```

which I think is more flexible.